# Woocommerce - Wrong rounded values in Cart

Tags: woocommerce

I have a problem with the round function (woocommerce) for the value in the cart.

Problem is that the value 8.4903€ is rounded to 8.50€. It should be 8.49€

Take a look a the captures:

In capture 1 I set the woocommerce to show 4 decimals in the prices so that we can see the real values.

In capture 2 I set the woocommerce to show 2 decimals. **Here you will see that the rounded values are wrong.**

How can I trace this issue? I already deactivate all plugins (except woocommerce, of course), so that I can be sure this issue is not caused by other plugin.

I already opened (week ago) an issue for this in the plugin author page, but nothing yet. **So, I guess if we can sort this out with a function in the function.php file of my child theme.**

I know how to use the php `round()` [functions](http://php.net/manual/es/function.round.php) but I need help to target ALL woocommerce values in the cart.

---------------capture 1--
[image]

---------------capture 2--
[image]

---------------capture 3--
[image]

Comment: @MujeebuRahman the output is 48.92€

Comment: @MujeebuRahman I think so, IVA 21% is a Tax value.

Comment: @MujeebuRahman fixed!.  I just enabled 'Round tax at subtotal level, instead of rounding per line' and the issue is gone. Thank you! https://nimb.ws/v4HA0h

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!. I just enabled 'Round tax at subtotal level, instead of rounding per line' and the issue is gone. Thank you @MujeebuRahman!

https://s.nimbusweb.me/share/2533555/4x99afoss5d7vtfny98w

Answer (score 0):

Round tax at subtotal level, instead of rounding per line

[image]